# Subprocess change folder permission on Picloud (an AMAZON EC2 server)?

Tags: python, windows, amazon-ec2, subprocess, administrator

In Ubuntu, I use `subprocess.Popen` to call an executable file, which will save some output files on the hard drive of server (Picloud). The code has been tested successfully on a Local Ubuntu machine. However, it does not work on the server. My approach is listed below:

```
#create a new folder. 
#The permission is drwxrwx--- both locally and on the server end
os.makedirs(folder)

#copy the executable file to this folder. 
#The permission is drwxrwx--- both locally and on the server end after copy
shutil.copy("a.exe", folder)

#call this exe file. 
#The permission is drwxrwx--- locally but changed to drwxr-x--- on the server end. 
#Since I do not have the write permit, my code fails
subprocess.Popen("a.exe")
>>>OSError: [errno 13] permission denied.
```

I am not sure why subprocess changes my folder permission on the server end. So I try to use `sudo` mode as:
    subprocess.Popen("sudo", "a.exe")
As I expected, this code work locally only.

So can anyone give me some help on why subprocess will remove my write permission?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you can run it with command:

```
subprocess.Popen("runas /user:Admin a.exe")
```

Comment: Does this work on Windows?  Because at least on Linux, the first argument to `subprocess.Popen` needs to be a list....

Comment: Have not tested it on Windows. The code works in a local ubuntu machine, however same code failed on the server end.